# How to get an alert when an exe process hangs

Tags: c#, process, monitoring

I have an exe file. Lets call it X.exe It is a console application that I created using C#. 
However, it hangs abruptly and I have to manually start it over again. I do not want to make any changes to the code.
I know we can use ProcDump or Process monitors from windows sysinternals. 
Can I use them to monitor my x.exe ang get alerted on email when the process hangs? 
If so, what specific command should I send over?
If not, what else should I use to solve this problem?

Edit/Add on: Should I use create a windows service, identify the process using .net's process.GetProcessByName function and check if its still running?

Comment: You mention that the process 'hangs', yet your title talks about throwing exceptions. Those seem to be mutually exclusive.

Comment: use can use Nagios; or you can dump to a file which is monitored by a process (smurf in unix) which then send alerts when the filesize > 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle that with, for example :

[AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) event, by subscribing to it and inside the method

- send a mail
- log it
- notify the user about fatal error ocured
- or any other solution you may need.

In this way you have one central point where your application will receive the exception not handled by your code and can process them in centralized way.

Just remember that, for example `StackOverflowException` can not be handled.

Good luck.

Comment: So, should I write another application and include AppDomain.Unhandeled event in there? Because, I dont want to modify the code for the current application I am monitoring.

Comment: No, you need to add that code to **your** application. Add subscription in your `Main` static method, it's not a huge change.

Comment: I created a Windows Service and I will try to adopt your suggestion in there.

Comment: It will not work if you subsribe to the AppDomains Unhandeld-Event if you are not in the same AppDomain like your application you want to monitor. So, whats the reason not to want adopt changes to your code?